# How to scroll a div using its child div

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have a div with children an img and a div in it . The img's height is lager than its parent div's height and the child div's position is fixed .
Is not possible to scroll the parent div while mousewheeling on the child div ?

Here is the jsfiddler you can debug : [`jsfiddler`](https://jsfiddle.net/20hms6yp/)

Comment: the jsfiddler is working for me....

Comment: @Federico  You can scroll parent div when mouse over child div ? Seriously?

Comment: Is working in Edge... and Not in Firefox and Chrome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change position from fixed to absolute in .map. Sample is

```
.map{width:500px;height:300px;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;background:#ccc;}
```

Comment: Not an option . I need it as `fixed`

Comment: use 'pointer-events: none;' in .map class if you want fixed position child

Comment: .map{width:500px;height:300px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;background:#ccc;pointer-events: none;}

Comment: @DeepakSharma   Is there any other ways ?

Comment: May be using jquery. Please check https://github.com/MichaelPote/jquery.forwardevents